# How to limit results from ls on sftp

Tags: ls, sftp, head

I am using OpenSSH_7.4p1 on Centos 7.7.1908 and want to limit the file results from SFTP.

I have logged into a server via sftp and trying to run `ls -t | head -1` i.e. get the most recent file.

However, it appears I cannot pipe to head. I'm getting the following error:

```
sftp> ls -t | head -1
Can't ls: "/|" not found
sftp>
```

Running `ls -t` is listing all files, which is a bit messy.

I can't seem to find the docs on this. Is what I'm trying to do possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Your `sftp` client is not a shell - use a shell for shell tasks. A pipe is a shell feature.

Comment: OK, is it possible to list the most recent file in sftp though?

Comment: You can always mount the remote directory with sshfs (which uses sftp as the transfer protocol) and then use your local shell tools

Comment: Or you can use `lftp` which is a more advanced SFTP client (supports many other protocols) and with which you can do `ls | head` or `cls -lt | head`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas why not add these as answers?